# How to create pandas column that counts based on a given condition being met?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of extracted forum posts where the opening post for each thread is represented by the number 1 in the thread_opening column. The post_number column counts how many comments there are for each unique string in the thread_name column (i.e. for each thread). While the thread replies column counts the number of comments in each thread. My data frame currently looks something like this:

| user_name | thread_name | post_text | binary_target | post_number | thread_opening | thread_replies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BoxCutter | It's Okay When We Do It. | ..... | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| Docket_33 | It's Okay When We Do It. | ..... | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Hearmeout | It's Okay When We Do It. | ..... | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| yez | Science | ..... | 0 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| Mainländer | Science | ..... | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 400z | Science | ..... | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| Farnham | Science | ..... | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 |

I'm trying to create two new columns, let's call them target_replies and target_openings:

target_replies should count the number of 1s in the binary_target column, for each comment within each thread (thread comments are represented by 0s in the thread_opening column, while 1s represent thread opening posts)

target_opening should equal 1 in instances where binary_target and thread_opening = 1 and will equal zero in all other instances

Desired outcome:

| user_name | thread_name | post_text | binary_target | post_number | thread_opening | thread_replies | target_replies | target_opening |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BoxCutter | It's Okay When We Do It. | ..... | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| Docket_33 | It's Okay When We Do It. | ..... | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Hearmeout | It's Okay When We Do It. | ..... | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| yez | Science | ..... | 0 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| Mainländer | Science | ..... | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 400z | Science | ..... | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Farnham | Science | ..... | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: You can make a custom function encapsulating the counting logic, then apply it by row. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Simply use `groupby` this way:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'user_name': ['BoxCutter', 'Docket_33', 'Hearmeout', 'yez', 'Mainländer', '400z', 'Farnham'],
    'thread_name': ["It's Okay When We Do It.", "It's Okay When We Do It.", "It's Okay When We Do It.", 'Science', 'Science', 'Science', 'Science'],
    'post_text': ['.....', '.....', '.....', '.....', '.....', '.....', '.....'],
    'binary_target': [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    'post_number': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'thread_opening': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    'thread_replies': [3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['target_replies'] = df.groupby('thread_name')['binary_target'].transform(sum)

df['target_opening'] = (df['binary_target'] & df['thread_opening']).astype(int)

print(df)
```

which give

```
    user_name               thread_name post_text  binary_target  post_number  \
0   BoxCutter  It's Okay When We Do It.     .....              1            1   
1   Docket_33  It's Okay When We Do It.     .....              1            2   
2   Hearmeout  It's Okay When We Do It.     .....              1            3   
3         yez                   Science     .....              0            1   
4  Mainländer                   Science     .....              1            2   
5        400z                   Science     .....              1            3   
6     Farnham                   Science     .....              0            4   

   thread_opening  thread_replies  target_replies  target_opening  
0               1               3               3               1  
1               0               0               3               0  
2               0               0               3               0  
3               1               4               2               0  
4               0               0               2               0  
5               0               0               2               0  
6               0               0               2               0
```

**Update after comment**: You can use boolean indexing to set the values of target_replies to zero where thread_opening is not equal to 1.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'user_name': ['BoxCutter', 'Docket_33', 'Hearmeout', 'yez', 'Mainländer', '400z', 'Farnham'],
    'thread_name': ["It's Okay When We Do It.", "It's Okay When We Do It.", "It's Okay When We Do It.", 'Science', 'Science', 'Science', 'Science'],
    'post_text': ['.....', '.....', '.....', '.....', '.....', '.....', '.....'],
    'binary_target': [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    'post_number': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'thread_opening': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    'thread_replies': [3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['target_replies'] = df.groupby('thread_name')['binary_target'].transform(sum)

df.loc[df['thread_opening'] != 1, 'target_replies'] = 0

df['target_opening'] = (df['binary_target'] & df['thread_opening']).astype(int)

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
    user_name               thread_name post_text  binary_target  post_number  \
0   BoxCutter  It's Okay When We Do It.     .....              1            1   
1   Docket_33  It's Okay When We Do It.     .....              1            2   
2   Hearmeout  It's Okay When We Do It.     .....              1            3   
3         yez                   Science     .....              0            1   
4  Mainländer                   Science     .....              1            2   
5        400z                   Science     .....              1            3   
6     Farnham                   Science     .....              0            4   

   thread_opening  thread_replies  target_replies  target_opening  
0               1               3               3               1  
1               0               0               0               0  
2               0               0               0               0  
3               1               4               2               0  
4               0               0               0               0  
5               0               0               0               0  
6               0               0               0               0
```